# Share Facebook Photo Album on Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have a page on Facebook for my church. During church events, various members will take pictures, then post the pictures to their personal Facebook pages. Is it possible to take these personal albums and move them to the page? With groups, there is the "Add Group Photos" button which you can use for the purpose. Does that or anything similar exist for pages (for page fans or even just admins)?

Answer (score 2):

Pages seem to have fallen into a bit of [disgrace](http://www.allfacebook.com/new-facebook-groups-2010-10) by facebook. While they will still exist for the foreseeable future groups seem to get more new features.

You should consider moving your church community to a facebook group. Pages are aimed more at hosting brands and creating a company presence on facebook.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to move albums to a page but you can upload the photos again though onto the Facebook page.

You just can't move them from a profile to a page.